# Not loading correctly after login

Tags: 13.04, login, .desktop

On a fresh install of Ubuntu, right after logging in, the upper right fourth desktop, and the bar at the top of the screen (I'm new to Linux, don't know what it's called yet), refuse to load properly, the desktop section staying black and the bar staying dark gray. it was left to sit, to see if it loaded, but there was not difference. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Edit: Also, the mouse started off by moving fine, then went through longer and longer periods of freezing in one place before stopping completely.

Edit: After a reboot, the black section of the screen was gone, but everything else was the same.

Edit: Both times, I was unable to launch applications.

Comment: The bar at the top of the screen is called the panel, I believe.

Comment: Please add as an answer what "solved" your question, instead of marking solved accept the answer that answered your question.